# Dinamically add filter clause in QueryContainer

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I already have two QueryDescriptor variables holding a boolean query build dynamically, like:

```
QueryContainer should_container = new QueryContainer();
QueryContainer filter_container = new QueryContainer();

foreach (var parameter in should_parameters) {
    should_container |= constructClause(parameter);
}
foreach (var parameter in filter_parameters) {
    filter_container &= constructClause(parameter);
}
```

When I try to merge this two variables to construct my query, like this:

```
var result = client.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(s=>s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(qr => qr
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(should_container)
            .Filter(filter_container)
        )
    )
);
```

debugging the result variable it returns:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should" : [
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        ],
        "filter": [
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Which is **not** incorrect! But I wonder if  there is a way to avoid using this two `should` clauses, and  get the following output:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should" : [
            {...},
            {...}
        ],
        "filter": [
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        ]
```

That gives me the exactly same result. How can I write it with NEST to get the above query?
I'm using elasticsearch 6.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All bool query `should`, `must`, `filter`, `must_not` clauses accept a `params QueryContainer[]` of queries, so for each clause, you could use a `List<QueryContainer>` to collect the queries for the clause, then `.ToArray()` the list

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var should_container = new List<QueryContainer>();
var filter_container = new List<QueryContainer>();

// TODO: add queries to clause lists

var result = client.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(qr => qr
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(should_container.ToArray())
            .Filter(filter_container.ToArray())
        )
    )
);
```

If you have a lot of queries in clauses, this [will be faster than combining *many* queries with the overloaded operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_perfomance_considerations).